# Importing dllexport nuget add in to xamarin

Tags: xamarin, nuget

I have failed to import this addin, below is my screen shot.

[image]

Has anybody a work around this?

Comment: what are you expecting to accomplish?  The package only supports x86 and x64, it is not going to work with a Mobile architecture.

Comment: I have xamarin studio and am using it to write a dll to run on windows. I have a mac.

Answer (score 0):

The error is because you are trying to add the UnmanagedExports NuGet package to a PCL project. The NuGet package does not contain any PCLs so the install fails.

You will need to create a different project type, which is not a PCL project, to be able to use the NuGet package. The project will need to target the full .NET framework and target version .NET 2.0 or above.